# Using Arrays in the Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if in Excel we have command like `ones` or `range` command.

I am using the following command in one of my experiment :

```
=TTEST(A1:A5, {1,1,1,1,1},2,1)
```

However, if the iterations of the experiment increase, you have a really big formula. So, Any idea if I can write the formula in a more elegant way so that I donot have to repeat **1**  as the number of experiments.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IT's a little ugly, but you can use a little trick with the `ROW` function to generate a series of ones:

The `ROW` function, when used as an array function, will return a sequence of the row numbers in the reference.  So to generate the array `1,2,3,4,5` you could use

```
ROW(1:5)
```

To generate a sequence of `n` ones just divide that array by itself:

```
ROW(1:n)/ROW(1:n)
```

To make `n` a variable, just use the `INDIRECT` function and a cell reference:

```
ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C1))/ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C1))
```

So your formula would be:

```
=TTEST(A1:A5, ROW(A1:A5)/ROW(A1:A5),2,1)
```

Or, more simply for your case, just divide the *range* by itself:

```
=TTEST(A1:A5, (A1:A5)/(A1:A5), 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer consists of so many little gems which I thought never existed in Excel. Even though I will not be using 1 all the time, but variable `n`, I got the idea how I can do it. Thanks a lot for your insight and help